# Guava loading cache - keep fresh until expiry

Tags: java, caching, guava

I have a specific use case with a LoadingCache in Guava.

1. Expire keys that have not been accessed in 30m
2. As long as a key is in the cache, keep it fresh irrespective of access

I've been able to get to these semantics only through the use of some external kludge.
https://gist.github.com/kashyapp/5309855

Posting here to see if folks can give better ideas.

**Problems**

1. refreshAfterWrite() is triggered only on access
2. cache.refresh() -> CacheLoader.reload()

   - updates timers for accessed/written even if we return oldValue
   - returning an immediateCancelledFuture() causes ugly logging
   - basically no way for reload() to say that nothing changed

**Solution**

1. set expireAfterAccess on the cache
2. schedule a refreshJob for every key using an external executor service
3. refreshJob.run() checks if the cache still has the key

   - (asMap().containsKey()) doesn't update access times
4. queries upstream, and does a cache.put() only if there is a changed value

**Almost there**

But this is not exactly what I set out to do, close enough though. If upstream is not changing, then un-accessed keys expire away. Keys which are getting changed upstream do not get expired in the cache.